# Tie Object's visibility to another object's visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to do what the title says. For example there are two DOM-elements a and b, where a is visible when b is visible and hidden, when b is hidden.

Is there a way to do this with jquery?

Thanks in advance!

**Since there seem to be some misunderstandings of what I'm looking for, here is a better description**

Imagine a website with a variety of DOM-elements. On the left and on the right site are a black and a red dot. The visibility of the black dot is changed via a button-click-callback. In my case, I have no access to this function, so I can't just add `$('#red_dot').hide()` to it. In this scenario I need to find a way to have the red dot show, when the black dot is shown and hide as soon as the black dot is hidden.

Comment: Care to share your HTML markup?

Comment: Do you mean you update the CSS for one and the other one magically reflects that?

Comment: well, you could use the same css  for both the fields which need to be linked. whenever you want to change the property of one, change it directly in the CSS which is common for both. i dont get it why are u asking this functionality in jquery, it just a matter of logic

Comment: @koala_dev The HTML doesn't matter for my question so I chose leave that out.

Comment: @dreamweiver What you are saying is, that I should change the properties of a css-class via javascript? How is that possible?

Comment: ^lol, that's what jquery is used for

Comment: For changing css-classes on DOM-Elements, but I've never seen someone changing the properties of a CSS-Class...

Comment: @Vince: using jquery u atach or detach a css class for a element. using `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. you can even set specific css properties using `.css('height','100px');`

Comment: @dreamweiver I know that, but I don't see how that helps me with my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using $(document).click as the event i'm listening to, rather than trying to listen to changes in visibility on a specific element.

Answer (score 2):

There is a techique called MutationObserver (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). So you can attach an observer to your element, specifically watching attribute "display".

Comment: Thanks! This looks pretty much like what I need. Unfortunately it only works in IE >= 11. We support IE from version 7 so I can't use it :/

Comment: Oh, i don't think there is any analogue for this tool in IE7, so you need some compromise =)

Answer (score 0):

You have yo hide them at same time. So you can use this code to show them :

```
$('a, b').css({display: 'block'})
```

and this code to hide them :

```
$('a, b').css({display: 'none'})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('a, b').show()
$('a, b').hide()
```